Privacy preserving counting
There are two parties, A and B. Now, A has additive secret shares $[x_i]_A$ ($i=1,\cdots,n$) and B has additive secret shares $[x_i]_B$ ($i=1,\cdots,n$), where $x=[x_i]_A\oplus[x_i]_B$.
OK, now the problem is to count the frequency of unique $x_i$'s. For example, $x_1=2,x_2=3,x_3=2,x_4=5$. Then, I want to have $[2]=2,[3]=1,[5]=1$.
Naive solutions could be:

Have a tuple $S$ of $n$ entries initialized as $((0,0),\cdots,(0,0))$. For each item $x_i$, compare $x_i$ with all previous values, if $x_i==x_j$, where $j<i$, set the j-th entry $(j,x)$ to be $(j,x+1)$. This method has $n(n+1)$ comparisons. (All computation could be done with secret shared value without reconstructing any original value).

Compute $H(x_i)$ according to $[x_i]$, this would be time consuming. You know even a simple SHA256 on secret-shared $[x_i]$ is expensive.


So, my question is, is there any better way to implement it?
